# SharedPreferences not saving boolean

Tags: java, android

I am unable to save a boolean value using `SharedPreferences`. The value is always `true` for some reason. This is how the value is saved:

```
 settings = getSharedPreferences("UserConfigs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    b1 = settings.getBoolean("Gravity", false);
    editor = settings.edit();
    action_G.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!b1) {
                action_G.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_align_right);
                txt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                editor.putBoolean("Gravity", true);
                editor.commit();
            } else {
                action_G.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_align_center);
                txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                editor.putBoolean("Gravity", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
            b1 = !b1;
        }
    });
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:

change code but  pref not saving ?

```
 settings = getSharedPreferences("UserConfigs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();


    action_G.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (settings.getBoolean("Gravity", false)) {
                editor.putBoolean("Gravity", false).apply();

                action_G.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_align_center);
                txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("Gravity", true).apply();

                action_G.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_align_right);
                txt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how is it possible for you to change the value of b1? b1 is supposed to be final in this scenario. my guess is that your b1=!b1 changes the value of a local variable not the global one. instead of using b1 use settings.getBoolean("Gravity", false); directly.

Comment: Does image changed on click ?

Comment: But whenever you click again on button it will give into if(!f1){ } so, it will store again true into shared preference. that's why it always return true when you get sharedpreference.

Comment: In the edit you forgot `editor.commit();` / `editor.apply();`

Comment: again, settings and editor both have to be final in this scenario. move them into the `onClickListener`.

Comment: please select an answer as the accepted answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a variable from the context of your activity in an anonymous class it needs to be declared final.

Therefore, the `b1` variable that is initialized before the `onClickListener` is not changed after the onClickListener is called.Since, the reference to the inner `b1` is not the same as the global `b1`.

So, Instead of using `b1` use `settings.getBoolean("Gravity", false);` directly.

Answer (score -1):

It happens because on every click in the end you convert your b1 into !b1(`b1 != b1`) means on every click in there are "Gravity" is saved only as "true".

Comment: this is not true if you follow the logic.

Comment: First you should show logic properly then you should give down vote.

Comment: if b1 is true when you enter the block b1=!b1 changes it to false. next time you enter it will be false.

Comment: @Sasan Ah have not mention that b1 = true; and by defaulf boolean is negative.

Comment: yes it is by default negative, only if the 'Gravity' settings does not exist.

Comment: by logic i am also not incorrect you can check it properly.